# Route Protection ReactJs/Laravel

Tags: reactjs, rest, laravel-8, laravel-passport

I am building an application, for frontend I am using React Js and for backend I am using Laravel. I want to protect my routes in which only users must enter the protected routes e.g. dashboard etc. and also role based authentication. How do I make that possible?

I have already access the API in the sense it is already working. I having difficulty on protecting my routes in the sense that only logged in user must access those protected routes

Comment: This is a relatively complex issue, as you can take such precautions both on the server and on the client. If you want to minimize your server load, then I would start by protecting the routes in the frontend. Are you using a routing library in your React App?

Comment: yess I am using routing library in my react app

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.